# How I can add <C-6> to a mapping

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim

I am trying to create a mapping that will close the current buffer and replaced by the previous buffer.

I tried this

```
noremap <silent><Leader>bd :<C-6><Bar>bd #<CR>
```

But will just delete the previous buffer instead closing the current buffer and showing the previous one.

It look like the `<C-6>` is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-6>` is a normal mapping (I guess you want to switch to alternate buffer).

But the way you call it is incorrect -- calling it as an ex-command. Normal mode commands in vimscript should be called with `:normal! sequenceofkeypresses`. For `<C-6>` it would be `:normal ^^` where `^^` is generated by pressing `<C-v><C-6>`. Even more, with `normal` you would have issues using `<bar>` and would have to wrap it into `:exe "normal ..."` as described in `:h :normal`.

Having said this, it would be way easier to use `b#` command to do the same...

```
nnoremap <silent><Leader>bd :b#<Bar>bd#<CR>
```

`:b#` is short for `:buffer #` -- switch to alternate buffer.

And to answer your direct question you can map it like this:

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>bd <C-6>:bd #<CR>
```

Note

1. `nnoremap` is used instead of `noremap` -- map only for normal mode. I doubt you want this mapping to work in insert/select/visual modes. If you do, then you have to change it per mode (they should be slightly different)
2. `<C-6>` is executed in the same normal mode, so no `normal` ex command is needed

Comment: Thank you so much, I adapted your implementation and works perfectly.